# Joining together 3 database tables

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have three tables in my Joomla database that I want to query to combine and then order by date, but I don't completely understand how to use the [join function in joomla](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase).

```
Table 1: __content
id , created, title, state, catid
'1'  , '2010-01-01 00:00:00' , 'ContentTitle' , '1' , '23'
'2'  , '2014-03-01 00:00:00' , 'ContentTitle2' , '1' , '20'

Table 2: __webcasts
id, eventdate, title, state
'1'  , '2015-03-01' , 'WebcastTitle' , '1'

Table 3: __conferences
id, eventdate, title, state
'1'  , '2012-05-01' , 'ConferenceTitle' , '1'
```

I would like to select all articles from the content table that have catid 23, and combine with the webcasts and conferences table, and then order the results by date so that I have a table like this:

```
id, created-eventdate, title, state
'1' , '2015-03-01' , 'WebcastTitle' , '1'
'1' , '2012-05-01' , 'ConferenceTitle' , '1'
'1' , '2010-01-01 00:00:00' , 'ContentTitle' , '1'
```

Further complicating things (I think) is the difference in date formats between tables.  How would I form a query using Jdatabase to combine and query my 3 tables?

Answer (score 0):

Use below query you will get the result

```
$q2
    ->select('id , event_date As date, title, status')
    ->from('webcasts')
    ;
$q1
    ->select('id , event_date As date, title, status')
    ->from('conferences')
    ;
$query
    ->select('id , created_date As date, title, status')
    ->from('content')
    ->where('catid = 23')
    ->union($q1)
    ->union($q2)
    ->order('id ASC, date desc')
    ;
$result = $db->setQuery($query)->loadObjectList();
```

And below is the raw mysql query to get the result

```
SELECT a.id AS id, a.created_date AS date, a.title, a.state FROM (SELECT id, created_date, title, state FROM content WHERE catid = 23) AS a
UNION ALL
SELECT id, event_date As date, title, state FROM webcasts
UNION ALL
SELECT id, event_date As date, title, state FROM conferences
order by id asc, date desc
```